# 'ip-config-unavailable' error when USB modem tries to connect

Tags: networking, network-manager, usb-modem, modem, mobile-broadband

I have got a ZTE MF-193E modem which worked fine before. When I bought this modem more than a year ago, it worked readily out of the box.
Now, as Ubuntu is progressing in version, things are becoming more and more difficult for me.

This modem even worked a couple of months back with Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit). Now, in Ubuntu 15.10 (64-bit), it can not connect.

I have [set up a mobile broadband connection](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-mobile.html). I have tried various strings for APN, but this has not been an issue before.

*(The modem works fine in Windows 10, so, this is not a hardware issue at all. Also, [Modem Manager GUI](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/modem-manager-gui/) nicely detects this device. SMSs can be sent and received without any problem.)*

When I insert the modem, it gets detected alright, a CD icon is displayed in Unity with the name of the modem. A few seconds later, 
I get a message box

```
Mobile Broadband Network: you are registered on the home network
```

near the network icon.

When I try to connect, the wireless icon in network manager applet starts those centrifugal motions, but eventually it fails to connect and a message tells me that I am offline.

The line I could isolate from `/var/log/syslog` is this,

```
NetworkManager[628]: <info>  (ttyUSB1): device state change: ip-config
> -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
```

Though, I am not sure whether this is the relevant one.

More lines from 
`/var/log/syslog` can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/syslog.usb.modem?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 1 - December 06 2015**

As pointed out by one kind member, tried the `nf_conntrack_pptp` module approach.

Executed the following commands,

```
$ lsmod | grep nf_conntrack_pptp | wc -l
0

$ sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
lsmod | grep nf_conntrack_pptp
nf_conntrack_pptp      20480  0
nf_conntrack_proto_gre    16384  1 nf_conntrack_pptp
nf_conntrack          106496  2 nf_conntrack_proto_gre,nf_conntrack_pptp
```

Then tried my modem, the same failure. No discernable change in the log either.

---

**Update 2 -  December 06 2015**

Executed as root,

```
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

No output on screen (terminal).

Corresponding log from the above point to an attempt to connect using the modem can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/syslog.systemctl?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 3 -  December 06 2015**

Installed `ofono` and then tried the modem again.

Please see the log [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/syslog.ofono?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 4 -  December 06 2015**

Again executed as root,

```
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Corresponding log from the above point to an attempt to connect using the modem can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/syslog.systemctl2?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 5 - December 06 2015**

Changed all "deny" to "allow" in `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-dispatcher.conf`.

Tried connecting. No luck.

A few network connect and disconnect with Ethernet connection.

Followed by `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`.

Modem plug out and plug in.

Tried connecting again. Does not connect.

The log is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/syslog.misc?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 6 - December 06 2015**

Executed

```
sudo killall ModemManager; sudo ModemManager --debug 2>&1 | tee /tmp/modem.log.txt
```

and

```
export NM_PPP_DEBUG=1
sudo NetworkManager --no-daemon 2>&1 | tee /tmp/nm.log.txt
```

Could not run `mm-test.py` due to multiple errors. Did find the file at the indicated location. Got this from, https://github.com/openshine/ModemManager/blob/master/test/mm-test.py.

The above commands are somewhat different from those in the Wiki.

The log files are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/debuglogs.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 7 - December 07 2015**

Executed again (after the suggested change in `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules` and reboot)

```
sudo killall ModemManager; sudo ModemManager --debug 2>&1 | tee /tmp/modem.log.txt
```

and

```
sudo NM_PPP_DEBUG=1 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --log-level=debug --no-daemon > /tmp/nm.log.txt
```

The `/var/log/syslog` is included as well.

The log files are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/debuglogs2.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 8 - December 08 2015**

The updated set of logs are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/debuglogs3.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 9 - December 08 2015**

***Test 1***

1. This time booted the computer from an Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit DVD. As soon as the computer booted, started capturing the MM log.
2. Inserted the modem. `lsusb` showed that it was being recognized as a
   19d2:1232 device which needs to be swithced to a 19d2:2003
   device. Since installation of usb-modeswitch requires reboot of the
   machine (and hence loose the installation for DVD run), I prepared a
   custom switch file and switched the modem from command line (`sudo
   usb_modeswitch -I -c 19d2:2003`).
3. As soon as the switching was accomplished, I was informed that I was
   on `Mobile Broadband Network` and a New Broadband Connection appreard
   in network manager menu.
4. I setup the above connection in the usual way (APN name was not an
   issue), and the connection was established automatically.
5. I disconnected and ejected the modem.
6. Stopped capturing the MM log.

The complete MM log and syslog for the session start to modem eject can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/DebugLogs14.04_32bit.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

***Test 2***

The same test with an Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit DVD.

The logs can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/DebugLogs14.04_64bit.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 10 - December 09 2015**

This time tested with `wvdial` and found that if `wvdial` is run as root,
we get a *successful* connection.

The `wvdial` conf and log, and corresponding syslog are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/wvdialtest.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)

Primary conjecture: the situation might have something to do with user group of the corresponding user.

But as indicated [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/SetUpDialer),

> With all these tools, to establish a dialup connection, the user has
>   to be member of the "dip" and "dialout" groups, so put all users who
>   are supposed to connect via dialup into these groups.

But as we can find,

```
$ groups masroor
masroor : masroor adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare family wireshark
```

So, the user is already a 
member of the indicated groups.

Now, perhaps the issue boils down to either of these points,

1. Which additional group does the user need to be?
2. How do we run the mobile broadband connection setup process as root? (security issues?)

---

**Update 11 - December 09 2015**

`wvdial` works with USB3 and does *not* work with USB1.

Please find the syslog [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/usb13.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

Also included is the output of `dmesg | grep tty > /tmp/dmesg.tty.txt`. But see those four lines near start of the file?

---

**Update 12 - December 10 2015**

1. Commented out line 4 (`SUBSYSTEM!="tty", GOTO="mm_zte_port_types_end"`) in `/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules`.
2. Rebooted my machine. Soft disconnected the cable and inserted the modem.
3. Tried to connect. Unsuccessful.

The syslog file is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/syslog.udev.txt?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 13 - December 10 2015**

Out of sheer desperation, to see whether some local changes are affecting the connection, tested the machine with Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10 DVDs.

1. Booted the machine with Xubuntu 15.04 64 bit DVD. The connection was successful like a charm.
2. Booted the machine with Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit DVD. The connection failed just like before.

What happened between 15.04 and 15.10?

So frustrating.

---

**Update 14 - December 10 2015**

1. Created a new file `/lib/udev/rules.d/78-mm-zte-port-types-RALPH.rules` as instructed in the answer.
2. Rebooted my machine (or executed `sudo udevadm control --reload`, actually tried both).  Inserted the modem.
3. The modem got recognized.

   ```
   $ lsusb
   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
   ```
4. Soft disconnected the cable and tried to connect using the modem. Unsuccessful.
5. Ejected the modem.

The machine hangs once, is that a random event? My machine does not
usually hang once in year.

The syslog file and the created rule files are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/udevrules.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 15 - December 11 2015**

1. Added the following lines to `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`.

   ```
   # ZTE MF193E
   ATTR{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTR{idProduct}=="1232", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
   ```
2. Left the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/78-mm-zte-port-types-RALPH.rules` intact.
3. Rebooted my machine. Inserted the modem.
4. The modem got recognized.

   ```
   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
   ```
5. Soft disconnected the cable and tried to connect. Unsuccessful.
6. Ejected the modem.
7. Removed `/lib/udev/rules.d/78-mm-zte-port-types-RALPH.rules`.
8. Rebooted and tried the whole process again. Unsuccessful again.

The syslog file (complete, I did not take the risk of missing any
important part) and the mentioned rule file (40) are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/udevrules40.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 16 - December 11 2015**

1. Left only one 1232 rule in
   `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`, removed the other
   one.
2. Executed `sudo udevadm control --reload`.
3. Inserted the modem.
4. The modem got recognized.

   ```
   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
   ```
5. Soft disconnected the cable and tried to connect. Unsuccessful.
6. Ejected the modem.

But did not we test the default system above? Did you mean to leave `/lib/udev/rules.d/78-mm-zte-port-types-RALPH.rules` in its place?

The syslog file (complete, I did not take the risk of missing any
important part) and the mentioned rule file (40) are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/udevrules40onlyone1232rule.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)

---

**Update 17 - December 11 2015**

1. Commented out the 1232 rule in
   `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`, added one for 2003.

   ```
   # ZTE MFxxx
   # Added on December 11 2015
   ATTR{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTR{idProduct}=="2003", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
   ```
2. Executed `sudo udevadm control --reload`.
3. Inserted the modem.
4. The modem got recognized as a ***1232*** device. I am not offered to try connecting (as far as my knowledge goes, it will not be registered to broadband network unless switching has happened to 2003)

   ```
   Bus 001 Device 008: ID 19d2:1232 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
   ```
5. Ejected the modem.

The syslog file and the mentioned rule file (40) are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/udevrules40no1232added2003.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)

---

**Update 18 - December 11 2015**

1. Put all the rule files in their original form.
2. Watched `lsusb` output every one second using a shell
   script. Captured output in time stamped files.
3. Inserted the modem. (The modem first appears in the file
   `lssuboutouput.Fri Dec 11 16:56:29 BDT 2015.txt`).  As we can find
   from the captures, it is clear that it switches from a 1232 device to
   a 2003 one.
4. Tried to connect. Unsuccessful.
5. Ejected the modem.

The syslog file, time stamped `lsusb` outputs and the mentioned rule files are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/update18.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

Now, you may want to match the syslog outputs with the time stamps.

---

**Update 19 - December 11 2015**

Performed this test in a completley new direction with the wish that I
could isolate the issues.

1. Saved in a portable media `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb-media-players.rules` and `/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules` (from the Ubuntu 15.10 machine).
2. Booted the machine using Xubuntu 15.04 64 bit DVD.
3. Executed `diff 77-mm-zte-port-types.rules
   /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules >
   diff15.10and15.04_77-mm.txt`. The first file is from the one saved
   from 15.10.

   Examination of the diff file shows no `idProduct` 1232 or 2003.
4. Executed `diff 40-usb_modeswitch.rules
   /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules >
   diff15.10and15.04_40-usb.txt`. Again, the first file is from the one
   saved from 15.10.

   Again, examination of the diff file shows no `idProduct` 1232 or 2003.
5. Inserted the modem. The modem got recognized as a modem.

   ```
   $ lsusb
   Bus 001 Device 008: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
   ```
6. Could connect readily after setting up a mobile broadband connection.
7. Ejected the modem.
8. Installed the latest USB_ModeSwitch.

   ```
   diff 40-usb_modeswitch.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
   ```

   Now returns NULL, as expected.
9. Executed `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`.
10. Inserted the modem. The modem got recognized as a modem.

    ```
    $ lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 008: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
    ```
11. Could connect readily.

I could have tried upgrading MM and NM to that of Ubuntu 15.10, just to see where it breaks. I actually tried but gave up due to endless dependency problems.

All the above mentioned diff files are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/update19.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 20 - December 12 2015**

***Test 1***

1. The `/lib/udev/rules` in original condition.
2. The modem device has not been inserted yet in this session.
3. Setup ModemManager for debugging and setup udevadm capture.

   ```
   sudo udevadm monitor --e |& tee udevadm.update20.WITHOUT78.log
   sudo killall ModemManager; sudo ModemManager --debug 2>&1 | tee MM.update20.WITHOUT78.log
   ```
4. Plugged in the modem and waited till it says that it is registered in broadband network.
5. Tried to connect unsuccessfully.
6. Ejected the modem.
7. Packed up log files.

***Test 2***

Repeated the above test with
`/lib/udev/rules.d/78-mm-zte-port-types-RALPH.rules` in place.

The log file names are self-explanatory.

All the above log files plus syslog and the 78 rule files are
[here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/update20.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

I wish all the log files came with time stamps, making matching easier.

---

**Update 21 - December 15 2015**

1. Changed the rule file as suggested.
2. Rebooted my machine.
3. Inserted the modem and tried connecting. It did not work.

The rule file and the `syslog` are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/masroorfilesforothers/home/update21.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

---

**Update 22 - December 16 2015**

As advised in one comment, installed various kernels from
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and tried connecting
using the modem after booting in each.

1. 4.2.8-040208-generic, failure.
2. 4.1.15-040115-generic, failure.
3. 4.0.9-040009-generic, failure.

So, perhaps, we can rule out the kernel issue.

---

**Update 23 - February 16 2016**

The modem has started functioning in Ubuntu 16.04. This version is still in Alpha 1, but works fine in my laptop.

Comment: I bumped into a similar issue in the past and ended up having to disable DHCP and using gateway address numbers from the cell company and using Google's DNS servers. This was two or three years ago and I don't recall the exact steps needed nor do I know if this is the same problem but the error was almost verbatim. Wish I could help more.

Comment: @KGIII I will want to give this a try. Just one idle query, if it has something to do with DHCP, how come it works in Windows?  Does DHCP server make any difference when allocating the address? Moreover, the same Linux machine (in which the modem fails to connect) works with Ethernet DHCP. Anyway, a real life experiment will be worth a thousand idle debates.

Comment: I'd *guess* Windows handles networking in a different manner and may have been already configured to deal with this specific hardware or hardware type. I haven't really paid much attention to Windows as of late so I'm probably not the best source of information for that.

Comment: @KGIII I tried setting the addresses. Unfortunately, the only two options available for a mobile broadband connection are two flavors of, Automatic (PPP). So, that is a closed road. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As far as I can understand the log, it all runs smoothly until the last log line dated "Nov 29 06:56:28", where some ppp module is supposed to get activated. This doesn't happen within the alloted time of 20s, so NetworkManager gives up and tears it all down. I'll need to learn more to be able to suggest what to do about it.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Thanks for your comment. The situation is exasperating for me. This modem has worked before in Ubuntu and works today in Windows. Then why should not it work in Ubuntu? I am absolutely clueless.

Comment: Over at (https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/507157-NetworkManager-pptp-doesn-t-work-after-lastest-update) was a vaguely related discussion, with the suggestion to
    modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp

A shot in the dark probably, but it may be worth to try.

Comment: At (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194042) you'll find a couple of more notes in that line of study.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Tried the `nf_conntrack_pptp` approach. Does not seem to work. See my update.

Comment: Ok. A few lines up in your log there's the note about "'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed", and googling it leads to another work-around suggestion. Namely, with the device plugged in, do "sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service". (Now we are deep into the NetworkManager bug list..) If at all a fix, it's not a long term fix, but a run-time patch that needs to be repeated.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Tried, please see my update.

Comment: Progress of some sort, I suppose. I would suggest that now it's the new complaint about "ofono" to deal with. There is an ofono package to install; do you have it installed? otherwise, please install it, and then man-handle the dongle once to see what happens (capture log please).

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32575/discussion-between-ralph-ronnquist-and-masroor).

Comment: Just to eliminate the kernel as a source of problems, can you try installing the 4.0 and 4.1 kernels from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and testing them?

Comment: @muru Please see my update 22. Does not look like  a kernel issue.

Comment: Sir, have you got any chat notification? If not, we need to create a new room and add @RalphRönnquist there too so that others can discuss the stuffs done and to be done..

Comment: @heemayl It was there but don't see any now. Please create one. So far, I have used only the automatic ones.

Comment: Sir, I have created a new one http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33038/discussion-on-q-703725  @RalphRönnquist please join the new room, we need you too..

Comment: He is at a +10 time zone. So, might be a bit late for him. Perhaps earlier in the day is more suitable.

Comment: @Masroor Sir, seems so..this is the problem with others too.."they" are in the wrong TZ :) ..we might have to rely on comments at the end :)

Comment: Yes, let's vote for a flat Earth, and then everyone can have breakfast together :-) ... I'll try to look in tonight; sometime about 4-8pm on your clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modem has started functioning in Ubuntu 16.04. This version is still in development phase, but works fine in my laptop.

I wish I could provide more technical details on how it started functioning.

Answer (score 4):

Loading the `ofono` package did good, probably, but apparently your modem model, ZTE MF193E, is not on the ZTE list. Comparing it to other ZTE modems, eg MF190J, this modem is likely to need the same special `udev` rule, to run `usb_modeswitch` when the dongle is inserted, and to achieve that you may, as root, add a new `udev` rule to the file
`/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`
with the following two lines e.g., somewhere near the `# ZTE MF190J` comment:

```
# ZTE MF193E
ATTR{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTR{idProduct}=="2003", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

plus a blank line, so it looks pleasant to the eye.

It's probably wise to reboot after that, only to find it all works like magic :-)

Or not. As you know, this is deep water for me, but if it still doesn't work, another ModemManager debug log would be needed, for another wild guess.

EDIT:

I'm now looking at the two lines in modemmanager.txt:

```
[mm-broadband-bearer.c:1254] connect(): Launching 3GPP connection attempt with APN 'WAP'
```

and

```
[mm-broadband-bearer.c:994] parse_pdp_list(): Found PDP context with CID 1 and PDP type ipv4 for APN 'wap'
```

I'm guessing the first refers to your broadband set up, while the latter refers to the internal binding to a "PDP context" (whatever that is). By the looks of it, the modem offers 9 alternative contexts, including one with `apn='WAP'`, but the `ModemManager` settles for a case insensitive match.

The case difference might be the cause of the subsequent problem: e.g., that ppp wants a `'wap'` configuration (rather than `'WAP'`) and doesn't find it, or that the remote end expects `apn='WAP'`, but gets 'wap' which it chokes on.

The first option could easily be tested (and ruled out, probably) by changing your configuration to use 'wap' instead of 'WAP'. You may have tried this before, but at that time without the `ofono` package, so another test won't hurt, although the second option is more likely.

The second option is also more of a problem, given that there is an upper-case "PDP context" match available from the modem. Googling this issue, it appears that case insensitive match is correct by the (apparently relevant) specification "3GPP TS 23.003 chapter 9.1", and a patch to do this was added to `ModemManager` in November last year (into its version mm-1-4, I can gather). So in this case, your modem hasn't been told, and it expects case sensitive matching, while `ModemManager` unfortunately uses case insensitive matching straight out rather than as a fallback.

One solution for the second problem is of course to use a different `ModemManager`: either by finding and installing a version prior to this patch, or (with enough spare time), roll your own `ModemManager`. But neither is something to do at a whim, so maybe we need to browse around a bit to gain more evidence that this is (now) the problem, and if possible find other ways to work around it. Or with a bit of luck, someone who knows something drops by...

EDIT 2

Yes, version rollback is not easy due to dependencies. And rolling your own is far from a joy as well.

Two possible useful tools: command `mmcli` and 
(http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/module-tester/).

The problem, I think, is that ModemManager picks PDP context 1 with apn='wap' where it should pick PDP context 9 with apn='WAP'. Maybe this can be addressed by using one of those tools. Either to be able to force a selection of 9 during connection, or by deleting the bad 'wap' contexts from the modem, which the module-tester tool is advertised to be capable of.

The modem-tester tool seems to be a java tool in the browser, so you need your browser set up to know where your java is, and you need that java to be known about. Then please explore that approach; I haven't used it myself, but seeing the screenshots, I'm guessing it will present the PDP contexts as the 'Data Calls' tab, where you first take note of everything it shows, and then edit the 'wap' entries to distort the 'wap' apn labels to be, say, 'wap1' and 'wap2' (so as to "hide" them when looking for 'WAP'). Then save and close, and juggle the dongle again. Grab a log; it seems syslog is sufficient now, in case it still refuses to play.

The `mmcli` command also seems useful in this story; do `man mmcli` to read about it, but I didn't see anything about PDP contexts there.

EDIT 3

Good call! to test from the DVD. That told us that I'm on the wrong track with the APN, and that it all lies in getting ppp to come up. At least, that'd be my new tree to bark at.

Firstly we take note that there's a version difference for pppd (from 2.4.5 to 2.4.6), but that's probably not an issue, as then everyone on a dongle would have been on this excursion.

Hmm, ppp; I need to stir up my last-millennium memories :-). Unfortunately I'm busy today, but I'll touch base when next I have time, to see how far you've come. My first back alleys to look into would be: 1) is the user in the right group? 2) are the credentials right? 3) are the ppp/chat configurations file mod's right? The ppp debug log comes out in nm.txt (as per a few days ago), but there should also be a way to ask it for more detailed logging.

EDIT 4

Ensure `/etc/ppp/pap-secrets` and `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` have group `dip` (using `chgrp` as needed) and mode `740` (or `-rw-r-----`) (using `chmod` as needed). Mine didn't.

EDIT 5

How about this tree, then: Comparing the working `wvdial` syslog with non-working syslog, it seems that for some reason `wvdial` used `ttyUSB3` while the non-working `ModemManager` keeps using `ttyUSB1`. I'm not sure if it's at all significant, but apparently but `ttyUSB1` and `ttyUSB3` both respond as AT capable modems.

So, as a test, maybe you can edit `/etc/wvdial.conf` so it under `[Dialer Defaults]` includes the line:

```
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
```

for the one test, and `ttyUSB3` for another; both running as root; just to see if there is a different behaviour. Especially, if using `ttyUSB1` is a problem whereas using ttyUSB3 is not, then it'd be good to look into how to make ModemManager use ttyUSB3 as well. For any other test outcome, I'd say we'll go back to chasing ferrets in ppp land.

EDIT 6

The dmesg log can be ignored I think; it's been like that in all logs.
The new syslog only shows the ttyUSB3 test, but maybe we can assume that life gets better if `NetworkManager` can be tought to use ttyUSB3 and ignore ttyUSB1 (for this modem).

I also found (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/819784) with especially post #10 disconcerting :-(

The apparently applicable `udev` rule in `/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules` doesn't apply, but'd supposedly be where to go. And, with only a very rudimentary, pre-101 insight into the `udev` magic, I would anyhow consider questioning its 4th line, which says:

```
SUBSYSTEM!="tty", GOTO="mm_zte_port_types_end"
```

I think that line needs an initial `#` so as to be commented out. In detail, my reading of the file is that it requires a calling state of SUBSYSTEM=="tty" and SUBSYSTEMS="usb" in order to use the good bits, including the "2003" product rules, and at least for testing, it should be safe to skip the "tty" filtering. And I don't have anything better right now.

EDIT 7

After having spent some quality time with my favourite search engine, I believe slightly more that the ttyUSB choice is a root problem here. The udev rule I pointed at is ok, and you should revert that edit.

However, I've started to believe that the configuration rules towards the end of that file, for product id "2003" are misleading. From the logs, it looks to me, that product id "2003" is actually the memory device side of the dongle, whereas the modem side has product id "1232". You can test this by replicating the two "2003" rules for product id "1232", in file `/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules`

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1232", ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}=="03", ENV{ID_MM_ZTE_PORT_TYPE_MODEM}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1232", ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}=="01", ENV{ID_MM_ZTE_PORT_TYPE_AUX}="1"
```

or better, add a new file beside it, e.g. named `78-ralph.rules`, but then you also need to add the SUBSYSTEM and SUBSYSTEMS protection around it.

Then, pull out the dongle, run `udevadm control --reload` (or reboot), and insert the dongle. And then yet another `syslog` capture, unless it now happens to work.

The effective problem, though, is that ModemManager discards the plugin `libmm-plugin-zte.so` at pre-probing, and ends up using a generic modem handler. If I'm right about product id, then this might be the reason; that pre-probing looks for a `ID_MM_ZTE_PORT_TYPE_MODEM` attribution, and this is lacking for product id "1232" (before the patch), with the effect that the zte plugin gets discarded.

EDIT 8

The `syslog` log is a bit short; missing the beginning where ModemManager fails to install the zte plugin. However, it's clear that the Generic modem plugin is used anyhow. Now, it may be that the `usb_modeswitch` rule I gave you early on is wrong as well; it decides to switch *to* "2003" when I thought it switched *from* "2003". But, `man usb_modeswitch` (which I should have looked at before) kind of suggest that it shifts *to* a product id rather than *from* it. In any case, the log shows that to happen. Thus, please change that rule to use "1232" instead, and try yet again.

If nothing else, at least I've got to learn a little bit about udev.

EDIT 9

Good. The problem is still (or also) that ModemManager drops the ZTE plugin at pre probing. The ModemManager debugging logs for 15.10 (log sets "debuglogs*") all tell the story that the ZTE plugin is discarded due to the vendor-id/product-id test.

*Go to the source, Luke!* I took this opportunity to sight the ModemManager source code briefly, and it indicates that the plugin as a table of vid/pid that doesn't include 19d2/2003 ... though, I haven't found that table source, so I couldn't verify.

Or maybe there's a timing issue here. E.g., that the ModemManager runs pre-probing while the device is 19d2/1232. That thought is aligned with the observation that having the 78-mm-zte-port-types-RALPH.rules udev rules makes ModemManager a little bit happier with the device. But then, why doesn't it stay happy and make use of that plugin when the device is switched to 19d2/2003?

Maybe more logs are needed :-) With ModemManager debugged, and also a capture of the command `udevadm monitor --e |& tee udevadm.log` (in another terminal) when you plug in the device. I got that command from (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingUdev)

Do this two times: once without `78-mm-zte-port-types-RALPH.rules` and once with the rules... both times from a fresh reboot. I.e.

1. setup `/lib/udev/rules.d` with or without the `*-RALPH.rules` file
2. pull out the device
3. reboot
4. setup ModemManager for debugging and setup udevadm capture
5. plug in the device and wait a minute
6. pack up log files
7. repeat from 1 with next test

That logging should tell where the ZTE plugin is dropped, and as I understand, it'll also tell about the udev event handling.

EDIT 10

(I'm almost at the end of my tether here, but I have one or two more breaths left:-)

Firstly, all the `udev` decorations seem to end up as they should, with just a couple of question marks in a couple of the attributes. In particular, the `78-*-RALPH.rules` should be thrown away; it's not useful.

I think I can read out something from this, but I'm not exactly sure how it should be fixed. Basically, as I see it, when the dongle is plugged in there is a flurry of udev events. Focusing on those concerning ttyUSB1, there is an "early" event:

```
KERNEL[3867.310990] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.1 (usb)
```

which causes the `usb_serial` driver to be loaded, and `/dev/ttyUSB1` to appear. That in particular causes another event:

```
KERNEL[3867.435102] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.1/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1 (tty)
```

I think that also triggers `ModemManager`. You have to go to `syslog` to see evidence of this, since there's no strict correlation between the logs. The event is time stamped `3867.435102`, and `syslog` presents its nearest subsequent `ModemManager` log line just after a kernel log line stamped `3867.437412`.

In my line of thinking, `ModemManager` should not be triggered yet, but only after the subsequent ttyUSB1 event:

```
UDEV  [3867.580427] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.1/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1 (tty)
```

which has attached the ZTE attributes.

In the MM log, we would be at the line stamped `1449934745.363291`, which apparently is a "real time" time stamp rather than a "kernel time" stamp.

`ModemManager` then is done with its pre-probing at`1449934745.450398`, i.e., 87ms later, which in kernel time terms would be near `3867.524519` and 55ms before that "good" UDEV event report above.

Note that in `syslog`, `ModemManager` does lodge complaints that `ttyUSB1` does not have its attributes set, and maybe that complaint is related to the "marking" happening in `80-mm-candidate.rules`. By the comment in that file, that marking appears to be an attempt to deal with exactly with this problem, but if so, it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Maybe one possibility to resolving this would be to change the "tty" rule in `80-mm-candidate.rules` to be:

```
ENV{.ID_PORT}=="?*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_MM_CANDIDATE}="1"
```

In my mind, that would ensure that the `ID_MM_CANDIDATE` setting gets delayed until the ZTE attributes are set. The `.ID_PORT` setting is an effect of a `60-serial.rules` rule (called `60-persistent-serial.rules` before), and the added condition to the marking rule is simply that it has a value.

The condition is not exactly a ZTE attribute, only so as to keep the rule more generic. One step more specific would be to rather require `ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}="?*"` instead, since that assignment here happens by `77-mm-zte-port-types.rules`.

In general I'm not very sure about `udev` rule ordering, and I'm also not at all sure that this really stops `ModemManager` from acting too quickly. However if it doesn't, then `80-mm-candidate.rules` would have little to no function, and maybe then it all would come down to the "improvements" to `ModemManager` from 15.04.

EDIT 21

sigh. Probably irrelevant, but you may want to check your `7-zte-mutil_port_device.rules` file; is that a remnant from other experimentation? Anyhow, not relevant here.

There's still almost a second between `515.558184` and `516.381549` where `ModemManager` eagerly and erroneously grabs `/dev/ttyUSB1`, and whilst complaining about it not being set up, still goes through pre-probing and discards the ZTE plugin. In other words, the rule patch doesn't make `ModemManager` wait.

I suppose you also tested using `ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}="?*"` instead of `ENV{.ID_PORT}=="?*"`.

Actually, to confirm whether or not setting `ENV{ID_MM_CANDIDATE}=1` is of any importance, you should temporarily move away `80-mm-candidate.rules`, then see (in `syslog`) if then `ModemManager` ignores `/dev/ttyUSB1` or not. I suspect "not".

And then, well, maybe you can use a working version, such as 14.04, and if you need, perhaps run 15.10 in a virtualbox, unless of course it's already all is in a virtualbox.

I think I need to claim defeat at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Please see the logs in my question.

Comment: Hmm. This log suggests it's coming up at modem level, but failing at ppp level. Would you mind get the nm.txt log happening as well, and possibly syslog, for a plugout/in gesture. Btw, I suppose its not also on cable when you plug in the modem.

Comment: Updated the same .zip file with two more logs included. I make it a point to (soft) disconnect the cable when making the tests. Though the cable has never been an issue before. Previously, after buying data packs before a travel, I always tested the modem in my home machine (PC) with the cable connected and subsequently used the modem in my laptop. Again, thanks for asking, there is no harm in making it sure.

Comment: Note my edit in the answer: next wild guess. cheers.

Comment: Tried with a  number of APN strings, lowercase/uppercase, everything. No luck. Frustration is on the way.

Comment: Yes, I think the option 2 problem is in the way here, but maybe you could try `Teletalk` as well (or again) and make a `ModemManager` log for me.

Comment: Installed the older version (1.0.0) of ModemManager. Got this during installation, `invoke-rc.d: modemmanager.service doesn't exist but the upstart job does. Nothing to start or stop until a systemd or init job is present.` Get this while trying to start MM, `ModemManager[10859]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.0.0) starting...
ModemManager[10859]: <warn>  Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name
ModemManager[10859]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
`

Comment: What frustrates me is two/three years back, even with 2G mobile phones, which I had to connect using cables, it was only a few `Next`s. For the modem under consideration, when purchased, this took less than a minute to setup and connect. Now, with the version upgrades and all those big name dazzles, life is this difficult.

Comment: New set of logs are there. Feel guilty for taking so much of your time.

Comment: No worries. I'm old enough to chose my pleasures ;-). New edit.

Comment: After some hard time, found that Google Chrome no longer supports Java. Invoked the application in FF. Now finding it difficult to make it recognize my device, Find Port does not work. Tried turning MM off since it may be occupying the port, no luck. Will let you know as soon as there is some development.

Comment: Since do not seem to make modem-tester tool recognize my device (did you see that is specifically mention two manufacturers, though there is an All), used the modem (successfully, seems  hard to believe to me based on the last couple of weeks) with 14.04 DVD, captured the logs. Please see my update. What could be wrong with 15.10?

Comment: Based on your, *"back alleys to look into would be: 1) is the user in the right group?"*, we may have some substantial progress. Please see my update. Are we seeing the end of tunnel?

Comment: Ensure `/etc/ppp/pap-secrets` and `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` have group `dip` (using `chgrp` as needed) and mod `740` (or `-rw-r-----`) (using `chmod` as needed). Mine didn't.

Comment: Changed as suggested, rebooted even. But it did not work. Hard to believe. Please see [this page](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1800), around middle, `Exec=gksudo "Teletalk_3G"`. This suggests that we are on the right track.  But this utility will not install in 64 bit. And the NM method should work, as it did three months back.

Comment: Tested and updated.

Comment: The discussion on udev rules is very very deep water for me. As far as I understood, you are questioning some lines in the rule file, which apparently moves the reader to end unless some tty is not found. Performed test and updated. Please see my post.

Comment: I had a feeling that this time it will be successful. But it did not. See the update. It may be mentioned that in the successful DVD cases, the `lsusb` outputs are identical to the one in  update 14.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit confused about the doable in last sentence. The created rule in `/lib/udev/rules.d/78-mm-zte-port-types-RALPH.rules`  already contains 1232. How should I change it?  Please be specific.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the very first rule I suggested in this answer, in `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`.

Comment: Right. One more test: apparently there was a "1232" rule already in `40-usb_modeswitch.rules` and just maybe this makes it switch twice. Comment out or remove mine (one of them), and then test it again. I'll keep reading the log meanwhile.....

Comment: Actually. It would all make more sense to me that there should be a switch rule for 2003 and no rule for 1232. That is, if the device registers as 2003 then it should be be switched (to 1232), but if it registers as 1232 than no switching should occur. I hadn't realized there was a 1232 before.... so: in short, put it back to be my 2003 rule,  then find and comment out the 1232 rule. Test, and weep.

Comment: Okay, ignore update 16, and wait for update 17.

Comment: Maybe I am confused. Could you please capture `lsusb` for me; it should tell which product id it is now and what that product id is. But there's all too much switching happening in the log file. Is there something else that want it switched? Where? How?....

Comment: Each of the last few updates contains output of `lsusb`.  Please take note of points 3 or 4 in the last few ones, update 14 (3), 15(4), 16(4) and 17(4). In the first three cases, initially it remained as  1232 only to get switched to 2003 a few seconds later, when it got registered in the mobile broadband. The only exception is the last one. And as my learning process goes, unless it gets switched to 2003, it is not a modem, it is a storage device. Please see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/433935/82650).

Comment: Thanks, apparently lsusb title is the same for 1232 and 2003. The thing is in the log, when switch to 2003, the subsequent lines suggest memory device, and when switched to 1232 they suggest a modem. to me. So this may be opposite for the one you ref'ed. Maybe a `lsusb -v` would tell the difference?

Comment: Please take note of updates 18 and 19. But specially for 19, please don't get misguided by me. My knowledge is very shallow and  I am simply trying to learn by supplying information to you.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a glance of this it appears this is not the first time this dragon has been properly dealt with. It was a bug before in 12.10 and 13.04 perhaps the bug was never fixed or a new patch broke something that was working correctly before.

Hopefully, If I am reading your technical specs correctly I would need to point you to this direction (MF190J):

[3G-modem (ZTE MF190J) still requires manual tweaking.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110075)

Comment: Unfortunately(?) the `usb_modeswitch` rule for this device was already in the standard rule set.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
 rfkill list up
```

and then make this script and run it:

```
 #/bin/sh

     Case [!$] in
        /bin/sh
        networkname="true"
        networkname="the ip adr type in here"
        nmcli nm networkname --force-yes
        resolve.conf the ip adr type in here
     endl
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Which IP address should I type in? This is a PPP connection.

Comment: -1 for writing a convoluted script containing nothing but incorrect syntaxes all over..also are you aware that `sh` is actually symlinked to `dash`?